# Awk group lines by prefixes into CSV

Tags: csv, awk

Using awk, how can I aggregate a stream of lines of this format

```
field_name field_value field_2_name field_2_value ...
```

e.g.

```
Company MyCorp Name John Age 38
Company MyCorp Name John Height 170
Company MyCorp Name John "Favorite Book" "The Hobbit"
Company MyCorp Name Henry Age 26
Company MyCorp Name Henry Height 172
Company MyCorp Name Henry "Favorite Book" "Tales from Earthsea"
```

into a CSV like

```
Company,Name,Age,Height,"Favorite Book"
MyCorp,John,38,170,"The Hobbit"
MyCorp,Henry,26,172,"Tales from Earthsea"
```

Comment: what is the rule for combining fields into rows? are there always precisely groups of 3 lines containing 3 fields each, in a particular order?

Comment: I assume the missing `26` from line 3 of your sample output is a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since fields can be enclosed in double quotes, you can tokenize the input with a regex that matches either a quoted string or a series of graphable characters, alternating between a key token and a value token. Keep track of the current company and name, and make them a composite key so that a record can be considered complete and ready for output when a new composite key is encountered, at which point output the header too if it hasn't been done:

```awk
function print_record() {
    if (record) {
        if (!printed_header) {
            print header;
            ++printed_header;
        }
        print record;
    }
}
{
    while (NF) {
        token = substr($0, match($0, /"[^"]*"|[[:graph:]]+/), RLENGTH);
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH);
        if (is_value)
            if (key == "Company")
                company = token;
            else if (key == "Name") {
                record_key = company "," token;
                if (record_key != last_record_key) {
                    print_record();
                    record = record_key;
                }
                last_record_key = record_key;
            } else
                record = record "," token;
        else {
            key = token;
            if (!(key in seen_keys)) {
                if (header)
                    header = header ",";
                header = header key;
                seen_keys[key] = 1;
            }
        }
        is_value = !is_value;
    }
}
END {
    print_record();
}
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVRNbxoxEL30tD-g58HKgS1UIanURqk4pCkpqhoOlBuiyMDAWixrZJtEKN1f0gtS1B_V_pl2196PeNfgw8qa92be-Hm8v57p4_pw-L1Ty7dXf1-9Xu6iuWI8gq1gkZoKnHOxaPrw5EGy2BKaJpRH8mhD83ExDZAuULyE06VRMNhHC2m17MwSjT072wgbPPZizyg8BixEaA7uXkoqvsYIuiB3M6lE86zThg1V80Dvzsn4B5m8IT_H4-uVoNvgejJpnfttGH7rDb6M-n7ZwlnHLjL8ProZjqDloKYmMDl9oOEOfeuEKbLGPXS7QG75ZkujPbEZ6ZobJNHTzdsmYSjRqjOgGyRVk9NlTJpqXlGTtImrqn2jOqfRhZDK_N7TkEukuJNiPuqFy2aSRspydWJci1Q6OJEfa2eOmFDkuc6vHbVPZqQcPun51tazCCRilDYifZczKTV7AU5HDJbIZJuks7ojVZLTtqKPcfKZJOSLijWOd5TPZ8Ju5PvyPfUGn7MTVe82Nr-H7C9x-PMvG2O4399ysYV0GuErDyK4WSG8u_KO4n1kq0DBxYfOcQ65ow9cMIXwifM1ATIKEPp8NmOKOLP6GIm9lr58f4JQaF-eINXFaYgSloJvoEeFCiRSYnz4Dw) or at https://awk.js.org/?snippet=nEkba5